# How can I make a graph with highcharts from csv file?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to make a graph with highcharts from a csv file.
Following is the data of my csv file:

```
0   1.03645399076138    18.680054645644 26.8678147836078
1   2.44625498591384    18.680054645644 26.8678147836078
2   5.45509322517529    18.680054645644 26.8678147836078
3   2.36362640018202    18.680054645644 26.8678147836078
4   2.28307829582599    18.680054645644 26.8678147836078
5   3.41138672777039    18.680054645644 26.8678147836078
...
```

In the first column is the data of the x-axis and the other the y-axis.
Now this is the code I've found and I'm trying to adapt.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {


    var options = {
      chart: {
        renderTo: 'container2',
        defaultSeriesType: 'column'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Ewarespar Residuals'
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: []
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Units'
        }
      },
      series: []
    };

    /*
         Load the data from the CSV file. This is the contents of the file:

                Apples,Pears,Oranges,Bananas,Plums
                John,8,4,6,5
                Jane,3,4,2,3
                Joe,86,76,79,77
                Janet,3,16,13,15

     */
    jQuery.get('/qark/1/graph2.csv', function(data) {
      // Split the lines
      var lines = data.split('\n');
      jQuery.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
        var items = line;

        // header line containes categories
        if (lineNo == 0) {
          jQuery.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
            if (itemNo > 0) options.xAxis.categories.push(item);
          });
        }

        // the rest of the lines contain data with their name in the first position
        else {
          var series = {
            data: []
          };
          jQuery.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
            if (itemNo == 0) {
              series.name = item;
            } else {
              series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
            }
          });

          options.series.push(series);

        }

      });

      var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });


  });
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are using C#, then check this https://github.com/riyadparvez/csv-to-chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should:

1. Normalize your csv result
2. Put correct option to your highchart

see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/DUYjt/1/)

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! I try it with "spline" and this the result I expected but how can i replace var fakeData = "0\t1.03645399076138\t18.680054645644\t26.8678147836078\n1\t2.44625498591384\t18.680054645644\t26.8678147836078\n2\t5.45509322517529\t18.680054645644\t26.8678147836078\n3\t2.36362640018202\t18.680054645644\t26.8678147836078\n4\t2.28307829582599\t18.680054645644\t26.8678147836078\n5\t3.41138672777039\t18.680054645644\t26.8678147836078", by my csv file I tried something but I failed.

Comment: @TakezoShinmen, Your csv result should be well formatted. AFAIK, most csv results are multi-line text(separated by "\n") and data in a row are separated by ","(I update the example to use ",", see http://jsfiddle.net/DUYjt/3/). It depends on your ajax response's text format. You can use your own way to parse (mostly use split function) your result, just make sure the output format is suitable for highcharts option, as the example shows for xAxis' category and series' data.

Comment: I just want something like that => http://jsfiddle.net/DUYjt/2/
I don't really know how can i change var fakeData by jQuery.get('file.csv')

Comment: @TakezoShinmen, put it in your ajax call back: jQuery.get('/qark/1/graph2.csv', function(data) { use returned data instead of fakeData here

Comment: I tried this   jQuery.get('/qark/1/graph2.csv', function(data) {
          // Split the lines
             var fakeData = data.split('\n'),
    values = normalizeData(fakeData), but I think I'm wrong i didn't use to practice jQuery ... sorry to be so weak T.T

Comment: @TakezoShinmen, can you provide your data format or a piece of your data content?

Comment: it's a csv file, this is a piece of my data :
0 0.934785856113144 25.2331473247096 34.4283248109657
1 9.49818946121924 25.2331473247096 34.4283248109657
2 8.17313737998374 25.2331473247096 34.4283248109657
3 8.19364952786688 25.2331473247096 34.4283248109657
4 7.85786050316547 25.2331473247096 34.4283248109657
first column x-axis then 3 points for y-axis and two of them make straight curve.

Comment: @TakezoShinmen, is that the value of your "data" in the callback of  jQuery.get('/qark/1/graph2.csv', function(data) {? if so, you need to use split function with proper separator to retrieve the value(seems like rows are separated by "\n" and items in single row are separated by two spaces), then use parseFloat to cast them to float type. It's easy, see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp for usage of split

Answer (score 2):

Look at this part:

```
jQuery.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
    var items = line;

    // header line containes categories
    if (lineNo == 0) {
      jQuery.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
```

Do you see the mistake?? You are iterating over a string! You need to split each line. If your values in lines are separated by tabs, then you can simply do:

```
var items = line.split('\t');
```

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g7d4W/3/).

Comment: Thank you it's better but I have 3 curves seperated and I want them on the same graph.In fact, i want only one graph with the 3 curves (I'm such a noob :() with the curve 1 (data from column 1) curve 2(data from column 2) and curve 3(data from column 3) tell me if you don't understand my english so bad these days :s

Comment: @TakezoShinmen So you want curves instead of columns? Just use `defaultSeriesType: 'spline'` in options.

Comment: hmm no, I'll give you an example because I cannot explain it well --'. X=0, Y=(1.03645399076138,18.680054645644,26.8678147836078)
X= 1, Y(2.44625498591384,18.680054645644,26.8678147836078)...
there are 3 points for each x-axis then y1 ans y2 are two limit curve for y0... is that enough clear?

Comment: @TakezoShinmen Is that [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g7d4W/7/) what you want? You need to define a different series for each column in csv.

Comment: yes it was something like that juste change the column in spline i success thanks both of you