# How to generate Highcharts JS live data graphs from data on other website?

Tags: javascript, excel, graph, highcharts

What coding should I use for this type of output?

Should I pull data to my database and then create graphs, if yes then is it possible that the tables in database get updated automatically (I am a beginner). The data is in form of excel file and there is a option to download that from there.

Because the final thing I need is live feed data interactive graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, we would export excel as csv and then import to Highcharts

Look a this:
[How can I make a graph with highcharts from csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11204371/how-can-i-make-a-graph-with-highcharts-from-csv-file)

Comment: What if the file is on other website? @raosu

Comment: Can you tell me how [link](http://www.welserver.com/WEL0521/)this get updated in every 2 minute with graphs?? @raposu

Comment: You have to generate every 1, 2, 3 .... minutes a csv, xml, txt etc .... and implement with Highcharts

look my example, is of my weather station, upload every 10 minutes [link](http://isocero.com/charts/index.html)

Comment: Yeah exactly thats what i want, so from where your graph is taking data and is it possible to get it updated every minute.. @raposu

Comment: How you have created this??@raposu

Comment: In my case, the weather station sends data continuously uploaded to the server in the time that you specify and format txt, csv, xml, etc ..... once on the server collect and transform data using Highcharts libraries in a spectacular result

Comment: Ok, I found another way to do it, I need help in that,I have website which also get updated and the data is in the table, so is there any way to get the particular value from the table and display it on the graph and I want it to get updated as the value changes on the table on other website.... If its possible then I would do that for different values in that table... @raposu

Comment: Everything is possible to do, but needs to learn, I can help you in specific cases, but obviously I can not solve it

Comment: Thats great, so from where should I start learning, I mean what should I learn to reach my goal @raposu